# Get compression rate from ffmpeg output?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

During encoding, `ffmpeg` accepts a "compression rate" (`crf`) parameter (different from the actual compression ratio) when the H264 codec is used:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf fps=15 -crf 20 -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

Is it possible to get the value of this parameter back by examining the video file? It doesn't seem to be part of the metadata, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mediainfo` and look at the `Encoding Settings`:

```
mediainfo input.mp4
```

To only show `crf`you could select it like so:

```
mediainfo input.mp4  | grep "Encoding settings" | cut -d':' -f2- | tr '/' '\n' | sed 's/ //' | grep crf=
```

Have a look at [slhck](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck)'s deatiled [post](https://superuser.com/a/576568/1137422) from whom I slightly adapted the `GREP`/`SED` command.

Caveat: There are videos where `mediainfo` doesn't retreive `Encoding Settings`!

Comment: Nice giving credit to slhck. But to use this you'll need to click on the dropdown picker on the Download button here and select your OS, then install the CLI not the GUI version. https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download.  And.... it doesn't seem to work. I get nothing staring with `grep`

Comment: It does work, but not all videos provide this info. I've added this info to my answer, thank's for bringing that up. This is very useful.
And you are correct, it's the CLI version.
A Package Manager like Homebrew for OSX is a great way to install the CLI easily: `brew install media-info`

Comment: in my case it worked if I simply dropped the grep and just used `mediainfo` and yes installed it with homebrew.